# ASP.NET MVC Unable to post data to server when there are multiple upload controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following UI where I am telerik controls and posting the data to server

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Storage", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmItem", @class = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="bg-dark text-center text-white">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Add/Modify Item</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:404px;">Item ID Name</td>
            <td>
                @(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("ItemName")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "Item ID Name", required = "required", validationmessage = "Enter Item ID Name" }))
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>UN Number</td>
            <td>
                @(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("UnNumber")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "UN Number", required = "required", validationmessage = "Enter UN Number" }))
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Packing Instructions</td>
            <td>
                @(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("PackingInstructions")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "Packing Instructions", required = "required", validationmessage = "Enter Packing Instructions" }))
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SDS Sheet</td>
            <td>
                @(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("SdsSheet")
        .Multiple(false))
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cargo Only?</td>
            <td>@(Html.Kendo().CheckBox().Name("Cargo"))</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example Shipment Ground (Fully Regulated)</td>
            <td>@(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("GroundShipment"))</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example Shipment Next Day Air (Fully Regulated)</td>
            <td>@(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("NextDayShipment"))</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example Shipment Freight (Fully Regulated)</td>
            <td>@(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("FreightShipment"))</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example Shipment Ground (Limited Quantity)</td>
            <td>@(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("GroundShipmentLimited"))</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example Shipment Next Day Air (Limited Quantity)</td>
            <td>@(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("NextDayShipmentLimited"))</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example Shipment Freight (Limited Quantity)</td>
            <td>@(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("FreightShipmentLimited"))</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button id="btnSubmit" class="k-button k-button-solid-primary k-button-solid k-button-md k-rounded-md" type="button">Submit</button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Download", "GetReport", new { controller = "Storage" }, new { target = "_blank" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
}
 <script>
$(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
       var validator = $("#frmItem").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
        if (validator.validate()) {
            var formdata = new FormData($('#frmItem').get(0));
            showSpinner();
            let url = "/Storage/Add/";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formdata,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result === "OK") {
                        hideSpinner();
                        swal(
                            'Item submitted',
                            'Item saved successfully',
                            'success',
                            5000
                        ).then(function () {
                            window.location.reload();
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        swal(
                            'Error',
                            'An internal error occurred. Please retry',
                            'error'
                        ).then(function () {
                        });
                        hideSpinner();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my controller method when I upload files up to some size it takes

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Add(HazMatItemModel itemModel)
{
    ItemRepository itemRepository = new ItemRepository();
    itemModel.FolderPath = "~Uploads/";

    if (itemRepository.AddUpdateItem(itemModel))
       return new JsonResult { Data = "OK" };

    return new JsonResult { Data = "Error" };
 }
```

I also added this in config but no luck

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
            <!--50MB-->
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

namespace HazMat.Models
{
public class HazMatItemModel : BaseEntity
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UnNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PackingInstructions { get; set; }
    public string FolderPath { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase SdsSheet { get; set; }
    public string SdsSheetFileName { get; set; }
    public bool IsCargo { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase GroundShipment { get; set; }
    public string GroundShipmentFileName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase NextDayShipment { get; set; }
    public string NextDayShipmentFileName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase FreightShipment { get; set; }
    public string FreightShipmentFileName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase GroundShipmentLimited { get; set; }
    public string GroundShipmentLimitedFileName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase NextDayShipmentLimited { get; set; }
    public string NextDayShipmentLimitedFileName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase FreightShipmentLimited { get; set; }
    public string FreightShipmentLimitedFileName { get; set; }
  }
```

}

Comment: can you please share your view model ?

Comment: added view model

Comment: I am able to submit if the size is fewer it seems more than 2MB or 3MB I can't submit

Comment: then increase the size from the webconfig

Comment: I already had it in the config

Comment: `<security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
            <!--50MB-->
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>`